# What's the best bucket fill algorithm in terms of efficiency?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, efficiency

I am looking for an algorithm that fills a given region of connected particular nodes in minimum time. I have tried using flood flow algorithm but it's too slow and inefficient for large array, it checks each pixel more than once.  Is there any algorithm that is more efficient than flood flow algorithm.

If that helps, i want to implement this algorithm for a paint filling app

Comment: How large is "large"? Most paint programs don't seem to have a problem using flood fill for images of typical sizes. I believe they often use very optimized implementations to minimize overhead.

Comment: 1000x1000 pixels

Comment: Smith's algorithm seems very reasonable, and operates on scanlines, while standard flood fill (e.g. not cached, naive recursive algorithm may visit some nodes even 9 times).